# How to create one-to-one accessor from one-to-many with extra join arguments with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have entity `Client`, it has one-to-many relation to entity `Address`.
`Address` has column `type`, witch can be primary (int 1) or secondary (int 2).

I can access client addresses through `client.addresses == [...]`
Now can I create accessors witch would act as one-to-one, eg:
`client.primary_address == Address(...)` witch would evaluate to JOIN with extra JOIN arg: `ON (client.id == address.client_id and address.type = 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [`Specifying Alternate Join Conditions`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) documentation, you can do:

```
class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = "client"
    client_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...

    addresses = relationship(Address, ...)

    primary_address = relationship(Address, uselist=False,
            primaryjoin = and_(Address.client_id == client_id, Address.type == 1),
            )
    secondary_address = relationship(Address, uselist=False,
            primaryjoin = and_(Address.client_id == client_id, Address.type == 2),
            )
```

This will allow you to access (read) both primary and secondary addresses as if it were 1-1 relationship. You can event set (write) it like below:

```
my_client.primary_address = Address(type=1, ...)
```

but you will have to ensure that the Address has proper value (1 or 2) for the `type` column which seems to be a technical field.

---

*Side remark: `type` is reserved word in python.*

Comment: `type` is a reserved word indeed, but as a class/instance member python is perfectly happy to accept that name :)